# Why does my child vuejs component property have undefined?

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent Vuejs component call App.vue which has a name property to pass to child component:

```html
<component v-bind:is="item.content" v-on:activateTab="activateTab" :name="sonamName"></component>
```

In my child component I have declared a property:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      props: ["name"],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("name: ", this.name, ", props[name]: ", this.props["name"])
  }
}
```

When the child component mount method is called the 'this.name' always prints "undefined".  Is there a way to reference the name value from props?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're trying to declare a [component prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html), which should be defined in [`props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) at the root of the object (not returned from `data()`):

```js
export default {
  // data() {
  //   return {
  //     props: ["name"] // ❌
  //   }
  // },

  props: ["name"], // ✅
}
```

Comment: To be clear the _order_ of the `props` doesn't matter so much as the fact they are returning the props _inside_ of the `data` object. I believe this is what your answer is saying but I just want to make sure that is clear for the OP

Comment: @maxshuty Yes, indeed. I edited the answer to hopefully make that clear.